# Re login after changing the Facebook password

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, login

I have logged in to stack overflow on machine provided by Office. I dose not log out when I leaves the office , Which I uses only in the office . I created my Stack Overflow profile using Facebook account . If I wants to change my Facebook password , dose SE ask to re-enter the password??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I wants to change my Facebook password , dose SE ask to re-enter the password?

We never ask for your Facebook password. We never did and we never will. We do as you to **log in** to Facebook in order to authenticate your account with us, but the password is with them.

If you change your password but remain logged in on Facebook, all this will happen behind the scenes.